# Update List Model with Ajax ASP .NET MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Can somebody give me a hint how to pass a list from the controller to Model list in view page after call the Action Result whit ajax in page. (Meaning update current list model with ajax call back result)?

This is my default load view page code:

```
@model List<ChargeSystem.Models.Message>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="container1">
                <p>@item.Msg</p>
                <span class="time-right">@item.MsgDate</span>
            </div>
    }

</div>
<div class="divContinMsg">
    <input type="text" id="txtMsg" name="txtMsg" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtMsg").keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: '/User/ajaxContactAdmin?msg=' + $("#txtMsg").val(),
                        type: 'Post',
                        data: "",
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                        //What can i do????
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    })
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the Ajax call action result:

```
 public ActionResult ajaxContactAdmin(string msg)
        {
            var result = new { model = messageRepository.Select().ToList()};
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

So, How can i refresh the model after ajax call back?

Comment: what does `result` has in it ? Add that as well .

Answer (score 1):

So what you would do is append the result to the existing result set.

Firstly I would add a container for easier reference, secondly you would add the item to the container:

```
@model List<ChargeSystem.Models.Message>
<div id="listContainer">
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="container1">
                <p>@item.Msg</p>
                <span class="time-right">@item.MsgDate</span>
            </div>
    }
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divContinMsg">
    <input type="text" id="txtMsg" name="txtMsg" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtMsg").keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: '/User/ajaxContactAdmin?msg=' + $("#txtMsg").val(),
                        type: 'Post',
                        data: "",
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                         $('#listContainer').append('<div class="container1">'+
                             '<p>' + result.Msg + '</p>'+
                             '<span class="time-right">' + result.MsgDate +'</span>'+
                             '</div>');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    })
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to enter information in your text box and save and update it in the view.
I think you can do this.

Here is an example:

Your Controller:

```
public IActionResult GetUser ()
        {
            var messages = context.Messages.ToList();
            return View(messages);
        } 
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ajaxContactAdmin(string msg)
        {
            var message = new Message
            {
                Msg = msg,
                MsgDate = DateTime.Now
            };
            context.Add(message);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return Json(message);

        }
```

Js in your View:

```
@section scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtMsg").keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    var msg = document.getElementById("txtMsg").value
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: '/Home/ajaxContactAdmin?msg=' + $("#txtMsg").val(),
                            type: 'Post',
                            data: { "msg": msg},
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function (message)
                            {
                                console.log(message);
                                window.location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        })
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Result display:
[image]

Comment: You should no be doing  reload on success

Comment: Thank you dear, but the location.reload(); is not real time change. its look like server side responded.